# Can't add a value at the end of a sparse array in android

Tags: java, android, optimization, sparse-array, custom-type

I have been playing very well with `sparseArray` until today. Now it looks sparseArray will not repay my love :(

I have to maintain the order of my objects I am storing in a `sparseArray`. There is only one method `setValueAt` that don't allow to set the key. `key` is important for me.

Tell me what is work around? Should I hack the source? Or If any one can help with a custom method which I can add in a custom sparseArray class of my own i.e I will code `MySparseArray` inheriting from `sparseArray` to add my that method. I need to add an object with a specific key at the last index or at the end of my `sparseArray`.

Comment: Not everyone here knows every fancy little class library any other user is using, so you might paste some example code of yours producing the problem.

Comment: Hi baby :P. SparseArray is not a part of some library. Its there in Android SDK. You know Android is a custom implementation of Java. It has somethings that Java don't have and somethings lacking which Java have. Moreover, its recommended to use SparseArray whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentations for `keyAt` I believe this should be how you add to the "end" of the SparseArray.

```
    SparseArray<Object> myArray = new SparseArray<Object>();
    myArray.put(myArray.keyAt(myArray.size()-1) + 1, new Object());
```

Documentation:

> The keys corresponding to indices in ascending order are guaranteed to
>   be in ascending order, e.g., keyAt(0) will return the smallest key and
>   keyAt(size()-1) will return the largest key.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html, there is the `append(int key, E value)` method - why don't you just use that one?

Comment: This method has doc which says "optimizing for the case where the key is greater than all existing keys in the array." Does this mean it will put this object (key-value) at the end (last index)? When retrieving <code>SparseArray.valueAt(size)</code>, will it give that object?

Comment: @ahmadalibaloch Why don't you try? There's also a put method.

Comment: please everybody, I am not new to SparseArray. I know put shut and gut  mutt. .append method dont insert at the end. I need to put an object at the last index of the array with a special key!!!!